# Unable to read value for variable outside loop in python

Tags: python-3.x, spacy

I am trying to create a list of dictionaries that contain lists of words at 'body' and 'summ' keys using spacy. I am also using BeautifulSoup since the actual data is raw html.

This i what I have so far

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import spacy
import string 

clt = MongoClient('localhost')
db1 = clt['mchack']
db2 = clt['clean_data']
nlp = spacy.load('en')
valid_shapes = ['X.X','X.X.','X.x','X.x.','x.x','x.x.','x.X','x.X.']
cake = list()
sent_x = list()
temp_b = list()
temp_s = list()
sent_y = list()
table = str.maketrans(dict.fromkeys(string.punctuation))
for item in db1.article.find().limit(1):
    finale_doc = {}
    x = bs(item['news']['article']['Body'], 'lxml')
    y = bs(item['news']['article']['Summary'], 'lxml')
    for content in x.find_all('p'):
        v = content.text
        v = v.translate(table)
        sent_x.append(v)
    body = ' '.join(sent_x)
    for content in y.find_all('p'):
        v = content.text
        v = v.translate(table)
        sent_y.append(v)
    summ = ' '.join(sent_y)
    b_nlp = nlp(body)
    s_nlp = nlp(summ)
    for token in b_nlp:
        if token.is_alpha:
            temp_b.append(token.text.lower())
        elif token.shape_ in valid_shapes:
            temp_b.append(token.text.lower())
        elif token.pos_=='NUM':
            temp_b.append('<NUM>')
        elif token.pos_=="<SYM>":
            temp_b.append('<SYM>')
    for token in s_nlp:
        if token.is_alpha:
            temp_s.append(token.text.lower())
        elif token.shape_ in valid_shapes:
            temp_s.append(token.text.lower())
        elif token.pos_=='NUM':
            temp_s.append('<NUM>')
        elif token.pos_=="<SYM>":
            temp_s.append('<SYM>')
    finale_doc.update({'body':temp_b,'summ':temp_s})
    cake.append(finale_doc)
    print(cake)
    del sent_x[:]
    del sent_y[:]
    del temp_b[:]
    del temp_s[:]
    del finale_doc
    print(cake)
```

The first print statement gives proper output

```
'summ': ['as', 'per', 'the', 'budget', 'estimates', 'we', 'are', 'going', 'to', 'spend', 'rs', '<NUM>', 'crore', 'in', 'the', 'next', 'year'], 
'body': ['central', 'government', 'has', 'proposed', 'spendings', 'worth', 'over', 'rs', '<NUM>', 'crore', 'on', 'medical', 'and', 'cash', 'benefits', 'for', 'workers', 'and', 'family', 'members']}]
```

However, after emptying the lists sent_x, sent_y, temp_b and temp_s, the output comes:

```
[{'summ': [], 'body': []}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You keep passing the references to `temp_b` and `temp_s`. That's why after emptying these lists cake's content also changes (values of the dictionary are the same objects as `temp_b` and `temp_s`)!

You simply need to make a copy before appending the `finale_doc` dict to `cake` list.

```
finale_doc.update({'body': list(temp_b), 'summ': list(temp_s)})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try creating a minimal reproducible version of this, as it would meet stack overflow guidelines and you would be likely to answer your own problem.

I think what you are asking is this:

---

#### How can I empty a list without changing other instances of that list?

I made some code and I think it should work:

```
items = []
contents = []
for value in (1, 2):
   contents.append(value)
   items.append(contents)
   print(contents)
   del contents[:]
print(items)
```

This prints `[1]`, `[2]` like I want, but then it prints `[[], []]` instead of `[[1], [2]]`.

---

Then I could answer your question:

#### Objects (including lists) are permanent, this won't work

Instead of modifying (adding to and then deleting) the same list, you probably want to create a new list inside the loop.  You can verify this by looking at `id(contents)` and `id(items[0])`, etc., and see they are all the same list.  You can even do `contents.append(None); print(items)` and see that you now have `[None, None]`.

Try doing

```
for ...
    contents = []
    contents.append(value)
```

instead of

```
contents = []
for ...
    del contents[:]
```

Edit: Another answer suggests making a copy of the values as you add them.  This will work, but in your case I feel that making a copy and then nulling is unnecessarily complicated.  This might be appropriate if you continued to add to the list.

Comment: Tried creating the list inside the loop but the error still persists. Also, del contents[:] removes all the elements from the list without deleting the variable itself. Then why do contents = [ ] for every iteration?

Comment: Adding the `= []` creates a new list and assigns it to the same name as your previous list.  It will have no relationship with the old one.  If you create the list be sure not to delete the values also.